# Dynamical system - System of non-linear 1st order autonomous ODEs: future stability

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, asymptotics, dynamical-systems, stability-in-odes

I am looking at a dynamical system of the following form (prime denotes derivation with respect to t):

$H' = -(1+2S^2+A(3\sin(\alpha)^2-1))H$

$S' = -\big(2(1-S^2)-A(3\sin(\alpha)^2-1)\big)S+1-S^2-A$

$A' = 2\big(2S^2-(1-A)(3\sin(\alpha)^2-1)\big)A$

$\alpha' = -\frac{1}{H}-\frac{3}{2}\sin(2\alpha)$

I am interested in solutions with an initial H greater 0. Further, physically relevant solutions are constrained by the equation

$0<A = 1-S^2-M$

where $M>0$ yet another quantity. Hence the maximum range of $S$ is $(-1,1)$ and that of $A$ is $(0,1)$. The above system is decoupled from the evolution equation for $M$, which is why I didn't list the latter here.

The goal is to determine the future asymptotics of the system.

From solving this system numerically, it looks like for large t one gets the following asymptotic values: $H\to0,S\to1/2,A\to0,\alpha\to\pm\infty$, where the sign of $\alpha$ depends on the initial condition. However, because of $\alpha$ blowing up, the numerical results become unstable after some time, and I cannot look at the solution at sufficiently large times to see if this is really the asymptotics or not.

The solution functions, in particular $A(t)$, typically look like some decaying function, which is superposed with an oscillation with ever increasing frequency, but which also has decaying envelope. So I would guess that the oscillation is not significant for determining the overall asymptotics of the system.

This may very well turn out to be wrong, but I never the less thought I would like to set up a system for which the solution would be the average functions, i.e. the functions where the small and fast oscillations are smoothed out, and what is left is only the decay, which happens on larger time scales.

I am however not sure how to construct such a system. Naively replacing $sin(\alpha)^2$ by $1/2$ seems to simple, but in a first experiment it looks like it would actually work!

Is this a legitimate way to do it? If not, how would I do it rigorously?

Cheers for ideas!

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  Are you sure that numerical solution, when the initial value of $H$ is negative, gives that both $H$ and $A$ tend to zero?  It is impossible, since then the "coefficient" in the first equation is eventually smaller than $-\tfrac12$, say, so $H$ tends to $-\infty$ as $t\to\infty$.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help! The physically relevant case for me would be an initially positive H. Sorry for failing to state that! I also didn't add the parameter ranges in the text, and had a sign error in the A' equation, sorry! I shouldn't write these things late at night I suppose.

Comment: I see that there is one simple solution, $H(t)=H_0 e^{-t}$, $S(t)=A(t)\equiv0$, and $\alpha(t)\to-\infty$ at exponential rate. There is another thing: if for some $t>0$, $S(t)\ne0$ and $A(t)=1$ then $A'(t)>0$, so the interval $(0,1)$ of physically meaningful values of $A$ seems to be extremely unstable (meaning that the likelihood that the values of $A$ leave the interval $(0,1)$ is very large).

Comment: Hi there, thanks for help! Yes, there are a couple of special cases, in particular A = 0 is an invariant subset. For the other part: If $A(t_0) = 1$, then $S(t_0)$ has to be $0$, or it would violate the constraint. So you picked initial data which is not physical, and then it may very well go nuts. So far I am pretty certain that all solutions  with initial data satisfying the constraint, are future asymptotic as follows: $H\to0$, $S\to1/2$, $A\to0$ and $\alpha\to-\infty$. Numerical experiments strongly support that. But I couldn't lay down an analytic proof so far. I think I am close though!